# Website graphics in a chef cookbook?

Tags: web, chef-infra, chef-recipe

What's the best way to provision website graphics with chef? I have a static site with a few images that I could use a cookbook_file to handle but I have heard this is bad... and if the site got bigger that could really increase the size of the cookbook. Anyone have any best practices for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the web site into a git repository and deploy that through chef.

EDIT: Generally speaking, Chef Server is not the right artifact store for this.

Comment: I'd still be committing large image files in to a repo.... I'm looking for a way around that... maybe a private image hosting service with an api...

Comment: Use Git Large File Storage (LFS). Both GitHub and BitBucket have implemented it. Alternatively, you can use an external service such as Imgix to manage your images.

Comment: The reason why its bad to do it with cookbook_file is the packaging. Every cookbook that references any part of any cookbook packages the entire cookbook together, even if its using a resource not related to the images in question. An image repository that the cookbook draws from is fine because you're not multiplying your storage impact every time a reference is made to the cookbook.